# ASP.NET Core 2.1 File Upload Form doesn't reach controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my controller

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost("Save")]
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveAsync(UploadDocumentViewModel Input)
{
    var filePath = $"{this.hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath}/documents";
    foreach(var item in Input.Files)
    {
        var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(item.ContentDisposition).FileName;
        var fullFilePath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
        using(var stream = new FileStream(fullFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
    return this.Ok();
}
```

This is the form that I am uploading from

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data",id = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Categories)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Categories, (SelectList)Model.Categories, "", new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Categories)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="Files" type="file" name="Files" multiple />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-secondary" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When I am trying to upload my file, I get transferred to a 404 page. However, If I remove the async Task items from my controller, I can reach the controller just fine.
I am trying to follow this Microsoft tutorial but I can't seem to get it to work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Yes, I remove basically everything and just return null. When I debug it, I can reach the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is attempting to generate a route for a `"Save"` action, but you action name is actually `SaveAsync`. It worked when you removed the async stuff, because you likely changed the method name to `Save` as well at that point.

It's not traditional to name actions with the `Async` suffix, even if they are async (unlike other types of methods). As a result, I'd recommend simply removing the `Async` part of the method name, and you'll be fine. Otherwise, you need to change the reference in your form from "Save" to "SaveAsync" to match the name of the action.

FWIW, you're killing yourself using the `HtmlHelper` methods here. Use the tag helpers instead. For example, your from could be as simple as:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: That’s strange though. Wouldn’t the httppost(Save) reroute the request?

Comment: No. Here you're specifying the action name. It will resolve to "Save", based on the route, but the action name is "SaveAsync".

Comment: Put another way, because you have no "Save" action, this will resolve to null, and the action attribute of the form will be empty. That in turn translates to a post back to the same page. To actually get the URL for the form to be the route for your save action, you have to specify the actual action name.